# add .pdf to the end of text in a text file - bash

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
#read the text line by line and cut off the extension
while read filenames ; do
    dataset=$filenames
    nameis=${dataset%.*}
    echo "$nameis" >> /infanass/dev/admin/test/parsed.txt
done < /infanass/dev/admin/test/tobeparsed.txt #location where file names w/ extensions are 

while read line ; do
    grep "^$line$" /infanass/dev/admin/test/parsed.txt >>matches.txt
done < /infanass/dev/admin/test/file1.txt
```

I compare my text between the two files and if they match they get sent to the matches.txt The values that get sent to matches.txt have no extensions (just names) i want to add .pdf to all of them when they get sent to the matches.txt Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Why do you need two separate files and two separate loops for this? The standard solution would be `sed 's/\.[^.]*$/.pdf/' txtfiles >pdffiles`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the last `while` loop into this:

```
while read line 
do
    if grep -q "^$line$" /infanass/dev/admin/test/parsed.txt
    then
        echo "${line}.pdf" >>matches.txt
    fi
done < /infanass/dev/admin/test/file1.txt
```

By the way, you don't need semicolons for your loops if you're writing a script in a file. They're only needed if you're writing a compound command on a single line in a terminal.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: if expects a command, `[` is a command, `grep` is also a command. using both as you have it will break.

Comment: The subshell isn't needed either, but that does work :D

Comment: @llua Thanks for the constructive comments. I usually use Perl as my hammer of choice, which is why I often mess up Bash :) All fixed now.

Comment: @JosephR. ./script: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./script: line 11: `    fi'

Comment: @mkrouse Fixed. Turns out that, while you don't need semicolons for your loops and `if`s, you do need newlines. :)

Comment: @JosephR. Learn something new everyday!

Comment: @mkrouse Indeed :)